# Check if data returned from sql table contains decimal list values in linq?

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

I want to return only those data from sql table which contains specific values from list.How can i do that ?

```
  List<decimal> userHeirarchyId = new List<decimal>();
  List<decimal> userGroupId = new List<decimal>();

 //Get groups based on user      
 string userGroupIds = (from ucp in db.UserControlPrivileges
                        where ucp.UserId == (decimal)AMSECSessionData.userId
                        select ucp.GroupIds).FirstOrDefault().ToString();
 userGroupId = userGroupIds.Split(',').Select(x => decimal.Parse(x)).ToList();

 //Get heirarchy based on company and usergroup
 userHeirarchyId = db.Groups
                   .Where(x=>x.Hierarchy.CompanyId==(decimal)AMSECSessionData.companyId  
  =>stuck here      && x.GroupId.contains(userGroupIds ))
```

Any help will be appreciated..

Answer (score 1):

Try this. Change the order how you're using `Contains` like 'your compare list'.Contains(member name)

```
var userHeirarchyId = db.Groups
                   .Where(x=> x.Hierarchy.CompanyId == (decimal)AMSECSessionData.companyId  
                   && userGroupIds.Contains(x.GroupId))
```

Answer (score 0):

Write it like this :

```
var user = db.UserControlPrivileges.FirstOrDefault(u => 
                         u.UserId == (decimal)AMSECSessionData.userId);
if(user == null || user.GroupIds == null)
{
    return;
}
var userIds = user.GroupIds.Split(',').Select(x => decimal.Parse(x)).ToList();
```

And then :

```
var userHeirarchyId = db.Groups
                      .Where(x => x.Hierarchy.CompanyId==(decimal)AMSECSessionData.companyId  
                      && userIds.Contains(x => x.GroupId));
```

Comment: what if `db.UserControlPrivileges.FirstOrDefault(u => u.UserId == (decimal)AMSECSessionData.userId)` returns `null`?

Comment: @NedStoyanov, thanks for your input, but that is common practice, so i didn't feel it necessary to write null check and all that. Just showing the logic. but I am updating it then.